# flextable background colour issues

Tags: r, flextable

I am making a flextable using the `iris` dataset and have noticed an odd issue with the background colour function. I am trying to conditionally colour cells if they are over a certain value:

```
 regulartable(iris) %>%
   bg(i=1, j=which(iris[1,1:4] > 5), "green")
```

[image]

It works fine if at least one of the cells satisfies the condition for `j`, but if non of them do it colours the whole line rather than colouring nothing:

```
 regulartable(iris) %>%
   bg(i=1, j=which(iris[1,1:4] > 6), "green")
```

[image]

Is there a way to make it only colour if the condition is met? Also is this a feature or a bug in the flextable package?

## Edit:

This has been resolved by version `0.5.1` of the `flextable` package.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. This is a side effect, when selecting none, everything is selected which is a bad idea, sorry. I will correct that but I must be careful (as it may break user's code).

Comment: No probs, I have a workaround for now so not needed urgently or anything :) Are you able to post an answer when you release the fix?

Comment: no problem, I'll answer that question when it will be solved

Comment: Looks like this has been fixed in the new release, thanks :) one small thing, not all the lines in the table have been removed. Is this by design as well?

Comment: I did not change the selector yet, it will be done in the next run

Comment: Yep, all colours are gone for me. all formatting is no longer showing, that's why I thought it was fixed :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is now fixed in version 0.5.1 of `flextable` package